# php,mysql prepared statements

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

```
function addAlbum($album){
        $connection = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DATABASE);
        $stmt = mysqli_prepare($connection,'INSERT INTO `'.TABLE_ALBUMS.'` (albumName) VALUES (":album")');
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,':album');
        $result = mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

            if($result){
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }

    }
```

i get this error:

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_param() [function.mysqli-stmt-bind-param]: Number of elements in type definition string doesn't match number of bind variables
```

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This time $connection->prepare() won't work. I can guess that if you'd `var_dump($stmt)` after prepare line, you'll get a `false`.

Comment: yes it returns false, any ideas why?

Comment: Possible your sql statement failed to prepare?  did you check the error?

Comment: It fails for sure if the result is false. Like Jeremy pointed, just check the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have mix both procedural style and Object oriented style

So, either use entirely in procedural style or vice versus

```
$sql        = 'INSERT INTO '.TABLE_ALBUMS.' (albumName) VALUES (?)';
$connection = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DATABASE); <- procedural style
$stmt       = mysqli_prepare($connection, $sql);       <- procedural style
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 's', $album);            <- procedural style
$result     = mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);              <- procedural style
...
```

Comment: ok that makes sense, i now get a warning, i have edited my question.